# how to write a unit test for keydown bind directive?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, angularjs-directive

This is the code that I need to do the unit testing.

```
todomvc.directive('todoEscape', function () {
    var ESCAPE_KEY = 27;
    return function (scope, elem, attrs) {
        elem.bind('keydown', **function (event) {
            if (event.keyCode === ESCAPE_KEY) {
                scope.$apply(attrs.todoEscape);**
            }
        });

        scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
            elem.unbind('keydown');
        });
    };
});
```

but the above part with ** is always not covered. The coverage report shows

Statements:75%, Branches:0, Functions:75%, Lines:75%

And following is my testing code

```
'use strict';
beforeEach(module('todomvc'));

describe('todoEscape directive', function () {
  var scope, compile;

  beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $compile) {
      scope = $rootScope.$new();
      compile = $compile;
  }));

  beforeEach(function() {
      var elem = angular.element('<input todo-escape="escape">');
      compile(elem)(scope);
      spyOn(element, 'bind').and.returnValue('keydown');
      var event = document.createEvent("Events");
      event.initEvent('keydown');
      event.keyCode = 27;
      element.triggerHandler(event);
  });

  it('should call callback function when the event happens', function() {
      expect(scope.escape()).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });

  it('deregisters on scope $destroy', function() {
      scope.$destroy();
      expect(scope.escape()).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

I am really new to AngularJS and unit-testing. Please help.

Comment: Can you update the testing code with the one that gives you 75% coverage because this one won't even compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how your test should look like in order to provide higher coverage.

```
describe('todoEscape directive', function () {
  var scope, compile, element;

  beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $compile) {
      scope = $rootScope.$new();
      scope.escapeCallback = jasmine.createSpy('escapeCallback');
      compile = $compile;
  }));

  beforeEach(function() {
      var elem = angular.element('<input todo-escape="escapeCallback">');
      element = compile(elem)(scope);
  });

  it('should call callback function on escape', function() {
    // given
    var givenEvent = { keyCode: 27 };

    // when
    element.triggerHandler('keydown', givenEvent);
    scope.$digest();

    // then
    expect(scope.escapeCallback).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });

  it('should not call escape callback when other key is down', function () {
    // given
    var givenEvent = { keyCode: 123 };
    scope.$digest();

    // when
    element.triggerHandler('keydown', givenEvent);

    // then
    expect(scope.escapeCallback).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
  });

  it('should unbind keydown event when scope is destroyed', function() {
    // given
    spyOn(element, 'unbind');

    // when
    scope.$destroy();

    // then
    expect(element.unbind).toHaveBeenCalledWith('keydown');
  });
});
```

If you have some questions please write me a comment and I will try to explain it to you.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I got a 50% coverage. one more question, why it says "if path is not taken"? What does it mean?

Comment: Not sure what that means, can you provide more info?

Comment: Even if the reporter shows you 50% coverage, you can be sure that the whole code is covered. First and second cases cover the binding to keydown event on the element and the two branches in the handler function. The third case covers registering $destroy event handler and its handling function.

Comment: Sorry, I mean in the code coverage report page, it says "if path is not taken" actually it says the same in another directive testing.

Comment: if you trigger the keydown event, it should exactly enter the if path right? so I am really confused why it keeps saying "if path not covered"

Comment: Did you tried to run the tests and all went successful. I missed calling $scope.$digest(); after triggering the event. Please try again and make sure that all the tests complete successfully.

Comment: yes it runs smoothly. scope.$apply(attrs.todoEscape) is always not taken, do you know why? Many thanks!

Comment: attrs.todoEscape is always string and contains the expression that you wrote in the parameter. To get the reference to the function you need to evaluate it on the scope. Example: $scope.$eval(attrs.todoEscape);